# mvc3 jquery unobtrusive validation locale decimal field

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

I'm working on localized mvc3 web application using unobtrusive validation.
In web.config I've got :

```
<globalization culture="pl-PL" uiCulture="pl" />
```

Jquery 1.4.4 and jquery validation 1.6 is in use.

Problem is with decimal number separator character.

I can see that jquery validation is ignoring the culture and is expecting a dot character to always be the decimal separator. I need to use comma instead. I think it's the same in German language for example.

I created my own methods_pl.js file :

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
number: function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
}
});
```

Above is solving the basic problem where decimal number is not recognized at all.

But when I try to use RangeAttribute on my model Decimal Price property it still doesn't work.
How to solve this?

Comment: See my answer here. You might find your solution! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204855/cant-get-the-jquery-globalization-to-work/9221040#9221040

Answer (score 4):

If you set

```
key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false"
```

the `DecimalModelBinder` posted in the previous answer will work, but you are disabling the clien-side validations.

To solve your problem you need to inlcude the correct jQuery locale.
Look a [this post from Scott Hanselmann](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) or [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/02/17/using-mvc-3-with-non-english-locales.aspx) they should give you some help in implementing it.

You should add the Jquery.globalize plugin form NuGet then in your DOMready function add something like that to have number validated correctly (at least it works for me)

```
 $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        if (Globalize.parseFloat(value)) 
            return true;
        return false;
    }
 Globalize.culture('fr-FR');
```

then add the relative scripts in your page

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.globalize/globalize.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.globalize/cultures/globalize.culture.fr-FR.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Phil Haack posted some information about this issue.

[See here.](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx)

In the post he desribes doing the following:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
    ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
    ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
        .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
    object actualValue = null;
    try {
        actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, 
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
    catch (FormatException e) {
        modelState.Errors.Add(e);
    }

    bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
    return actualValue;
    }
}
```

and then in Global.asax

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

I'm not sure if this resolves the problem on the client as well (Phil seems to indicate it will work), but it should resolve the issue on the server side at the least.

Comment: if the client side has different culture than the server side then you have a problem even with this code

Comment: I set culture and uiCulture in web.config like thie : <globalization culture="pl-PL" uiCulture="pl" /> - that's setting both server side and client side culture right?

Comment: Above DecimalModelBinder works fine for me. Any clue why in valueResult.Culture.NativeName is "Invariant Language (Invariant Country)"? This is probably the source of my problem in the first place. If the DefaultModelBinder is not using my pl-PL culture then it won't work. How do I set correct culture for DefaultModelBinder?