# MVC3 Razor globilization, double client side validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, globalization, currentculture, jquery-globalization

I am having some problems with "," in the client validation, ie. I am trying to validate a double number like 124,51 in "en-EN" culture this would be 124.51

I have tried to set the culture in the Application_Start() and other fixes without any luck, does anyone know how I can fix this (other than to disable the validation) ?

cheers 
sushiBite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install jquery globalization and then handle the load of the file with the Culture you need.
Like you would do with the calendar.ui cultures of JQuery calendars.

Basically you need to find a way to know wich culture you need to load from the DOMReady event and then act accordinlgy.

[Look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224046/394028). In the link at the article of Hanselmann you will find a, imo, smart way of setting the needed culture using `meta` in your pages.
(the article references an old version of globalization, but in my answer you will see the new name to use)

Comment: thanks, I needed to update the jquery code, they are not using $.global.culture.name but Globalize.culture().name, but it is working now, Thanks :)