# $.getJSON Not working in deployment server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, getjson, jquery-globalize

I used this post [Globalize error with local numbers on .Net MVC Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790008/globalize-error-with-local-numbers-on-net-mvc-project/37632053?noredirect=1#comment62746511_37632053) to install the new version of Globalize in Asp Mvc Application.

So In the _Layout.cshtml I added this code

```
<script>

(function () {

    $(function () {
        $.when(
              $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
              $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/fr/numbers.json"),
              $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
              $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/fr/ca-gregorian.json"),
              $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/fr/timeZoneNames.json"),
              $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/timeData.json"),
              $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/weekData.json")
            ).then(function () {

                // Normalize $.get results, we only need the JSON, not the request statuses.
                return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
                    return result[0];
                });

            }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
                var culture = "fr";
                Globalize.locale(culture);
            });
    });
})();


</script>
```

But when i deploy in the server it doesn't work.

Ps: I added this in my web.config

```
<system.webServer>
...
<staticContent>
  <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
</staticContent>

</system.webServer>
```

Please Help.

Comment: Have you checked the Chrome console for any errors?

Comment: I have this errors GET http://localhost/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json 404 (Not Found) ....

Comment: Great!Glad I could put you on the right path to fix your problem

Comment: The problem is resolved when i add MyWebSiteName in $.GetJson like this $.getJSON("/MyWebSiteName/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"). But i think it's not the better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$.getJSON(@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json")),
$.getJSON(@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/main/fr/numbers.json")),...
```

Might need to wrap it around in double quotes, just play around a little with the `@Url.Content` but I believe it will solve your problem

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json")"),
$.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/main/fr/numbers.json")"),...
```

Comment: $.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json")"),
$.getJSON("@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cldr/main/fr/numbers.json")"),...