# Decimal value not showing correctly in html td

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Decimal value not showing correctly in html td.
Here is the code:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>@Model.ActualExpenceEntry.Allowance</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

where `@Model.ActualExpenceEntry.Allowance` is the decimal value like `123.365`. But in HTML it shows like `123,365`. I want to show as it is..

Comment: Are you running localhost or on a server? If a server, what country/locale is it set to?

Comment: yes its a language issue. some country valid `float` value is with `,`

Comment: running in localhost

Comment: What is your PC's country/locale set to and the same question for your browser?

Comment: This is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790008/globalize-error-with-local-numbers-on-net-mvc-project for that answer check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204855/cant-get-the-jquery-globalization-to-work

Comment: location is in India

Comment: The only different thing about number formatting in India is usually the position of the commas (every 2 digits after the first 3). Check your PC's locale settings (and the browser).

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>@Model.ActualExpenceEntry.Allowance.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This way you force the number to be displayed in the invariant culture which among other means also that the dot (.) will be used as a decimal separator.

However you may want to set up a culture info in your web.config file so the same number format is used across the whole application - e.g.:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then you of course do not need the hack with `.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 0):

is't depend on client culture, use configuration to solve it.

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="xx-XX" uiCulture="xx-XX" />
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way floating-point values (`float`, `double`, `decimal`) are displayed are heavily dependent on locale.

Some locales use `,` as decimal-separator, some use `.`.

There are multiple ways to solve your problem. If this is the only place in which you want to display decimals with a `.`, rather than a `,`, then i would recommend using `.ToString()` with a custom format (or locale)

Example

```
<td>@Model.ActualExpenceEntry.Allowance.ToString("0.##")</td>
```

This will use the current threads culture.

Using the `InvariantCulture`, will also display the number with a `.` as decimal-separator.

```
<td>@Model.ActualExpenceEntry.Allowance.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)</td>
```

---

Another way to solve the problem is to change the culture for the project *globally*, this however might for instance mess up number parsing and "print-outs".

For instance, for `Double.Parse()` will ignore `,` and parse `"1,5"` to `15`. Which might be an easy thing to overlook.

@Gurgen_Sargsyan provided an example on how to do this via web.config

> it's depend on client culture, use configuration to solve it.
>
> ```
>   <system.web>
>    <globalization culture="xx-XX" uiCulture="xx-XX" />
>   </system.web>
> ```

Where xx-XX is a valid cutlure, for instance `en-GB`, or `en-US`. Leaving it empty will cause your application to fall back on `InvariantCulture`.